# unexpected error when using my databasecontext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, dbcontext

I'm getting this error

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>   The entity type tblMessage is not part of the model for the current context.

It also says that C. can't be used because it isn't defined. I do something similar earlier in the code and haven't had any issues with my chatcontext before.

I'm trying to retrieve messages from my database table called `tblMessages`.

Constructor:

```
public JsonResult ConversationWithContact(int contact)
{
        if (Session["UserID"] == null)
        {
            return Json(new {status = "error", message = "User is not logged in"});
        }

        //var currentUser = (Models.tblUser)Session["UserID"];

        var conversations = new List<Models.tblMessage>();

        using (var db = new Models.ChatContext())
        {
            int currentUserId = (int)Session["UserID"];
            var currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
            conversations = db.Conversations.Where(c => (c.receiverId == currentUser.Id
                                                         && c.senderId == contact) ||
                                                        (c.receiverId == contact
                                                         && c.senderId == currentUser.Id))
                .OrderBy(c => c.created_at)
                .ToList();
        }

        return Json(
            new {status = "success", data = conversations},
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        );
}
```

Context:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Trinity.Controllers;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Trinity.Models
{
    public class ChatContext : DbContext
    {
        public ChatContext() : base("TrinityEntities")
        {
        }

        public static ChatContext Create()
        {
            return new ChatContext();
        }

        public DbSet<tblUser> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<tblMessage> Conversations { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Database model tblmessage class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Trinity.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    public partial class tblMessage
    {
        public tblMessage()
        {
            status = messageStatus.Sent;
        }

        public enum messageStatus
        {
            Sent,
            Delivered
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int senderId { get; set; }
        public int receiverId { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public messageStatus status { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Database model tblmessage class:

```
namespace Trinity.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class tblUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[^\W\d_]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only letters allowed in your name")]

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[^\W\d_]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only letters allowed in your name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string BIO { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("E-Mail")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Incorrect E-mail Format")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W]).*$", ErrorMessage = "Password must be 8 charhacters, contain atleast 1 digit and one special character")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage ="Passwords are not the same")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public string Photo { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Age")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public string Sex { get; set; }

        public string Preferred { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using migrations?

Comment: Ok, in your database does the table `Conversations` exist? from the error, it suggests that it can't find the relevant table.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane no the table is called tblMessages `public DbSet<tblMessage> Conversations { get; set; }`I thought this sorted that out since it does for user

Comment: I'd suspect that there's another part in your `ChatContext` class that maps the `tblUser` entity to what I assume is the `tblUsers` table in your db. Posting the ful `ChatContext` class would help.

Comment: Has your database changed?  The is some inconsistency between the database and the project mapping to the database.  You have a general exception indicating some inconsistency.  Possible the variable type different. You have a DateTime object which may be causing issue.  Net Library does not allow for Null dates and database may have a null.   Also some database uses 1/1/1 as starting date while other use 1/1/1900, or some uses unix time starting 1/1/1970.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane added the tblUser class that seems to work and the full chatcontext and tblmessage. Just want to thank you for the help you have already given!

Comment: @jdweng I just edited the full table model in

Comment: Is there an edmx file with a visual model of the entities? Do yo know if the project was code-first or database-first?

Comment: @BarryO'Kane yes there is a edmx file it was code first but this table got edited alot while coding

Comment: It seems like @jdweng said, there's a disconnect between the model and the context. I'd have a look at the mappings in the edmx and see if it looks like the table is mapped correctly. Failing that you can right click in the edmx file model and try `update from database`

Comment: What type database are you using?  Is it Trinity?  See : https://community.trinitycore.org/topic/13962-trouble-with-your-trinity-install-starting-login-readme-1st-faqs/  It uses ADO so maybe issue with version of ADO installed or changed?  Was Microsoft Office changed?  ADO uses following follow : C:\Program Files\Common Files\system\ado  number in file corresponds to Version of Office.  Office may of changed but code was not recompiled.

Comment: Try making copy of Database and then try opening with Access.  Access may give better error message or even update database so it is compatible with version installed on machine.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane and jdweng thnaks alot deleting the table in the edmx and reading it fixed the issue!!